# How to print CODE128 barcode to POS Thermal printer properly using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, printing, barcode, pascal, epson

I am trying to print code128 barcode directly to POS printer using this code:

```
DirectToPrinter(chr(29)+chr(107)+chr(72)+Chr(123)+Chr(65)+'8600123456789', true);
```

According to the documentation here: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=128, I have included { (123) and character for code A (65), but I wonder why I am getting only digits printed out but no lines.

Any idea?

By the way, I am using EPSON TM88V POS Thermal Printer.

```
nction tform1.DirectToPrinter(S: AnsiString; NextLine: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  Buff: TPrnBuffRec;
  TestInt: Integer;
  i: integer;
   Device: PChar;
  Driver: PChar;
  Port: PChar;
begin
  TestInt := PassThrough;
  if Escape(Printer.Handle, QUERYESCSUPPORT, SizeOf(TESTINT), @testint, nil) > 0 then
  begin
    if NextLine then  S := S + #13 + #10;
    StrPCopy(Buff.Buff_1, S);
    Buff.bufflength := StrLen(Buff.Buff_1);
    Escape(Printer.Canvas.Handle, Passthrough, 0, @buff, nil);
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi version? How are you using those characters (show the complete code)? Why is the third character `chr(72)`, which defines CODE93, if you want to send CODE128? Please edit your question to include a complete [mre].

Comment: I am using 10.3. Yes, you are right, it should be chr(73) in this case.
I solved it by adding the number of characters (chr(13)), like this: 

DirectToPrinter(
          chr(29)+chr(107)+chr(73)+chr(13)+chr(123)+Chr(65)+'8600123456789',
          true
        );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved (kudos to Tom) by adding the number of characters chr(13) and replacing chr(72) to chr(73), like this:

```
DirectToPrinter( chr(29)+chr(107)+chr(73)+chr(13)+chr(123)+Chr(65)+'8600123456789', true );
```